# How to save canvas image in to database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html5-canvas

i did insert image in to the canvas. now i need to upload that image in to the data base, any one can help me to that.
here is my canvas code,

[here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjYem.jpg)

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Hi, here are some guidelines for your answer: Please **Do Not** post your code as an image, post is as a text instead. [Here is why you should not post your code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15366635)

Comment: oops on the comment above i meant to say *here are some guidelines for your question*

Answer (score 1):

Use Blob data types to save images in the database. You can easly convert images by using codes like imagecreatefromjpeg() or something else.